# cannot write full data in text file in java

Tags: java

I try to write a clob data using outputstream.write() in a text file with download option .But it only write the first line. how can i write the full data. Here is my code :

```
        OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        oRs=oStmt.executeQuery("select subtxt  from mybank.dt_subject  where mailid = '"+sMailID+"' and sessionid = '"+sSessionID+"'");
        while(oRs.next()){

             outputResult = oRs.getString(1);
             outputStream.write(outputResult.getBytes());                
             response.setContentType("text/plain");
             response.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment; filename=\"" +sFileName+".txt\"");
             outputStream.flush();
             outputStream.close();

        }
```

Comment: That is because you call `outputStream.close();` before you have finished writing all data into the file. Call it after the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are closing the stream at the first iteration (`next()`).

Obviously you can't write past the first line, after that.

Answer (score 0):

Like already said - close your outputStream after the while loop:

```
 OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
    oRs = oStmt.executeQuery("select subtxt  from mybank.dt_subject  where mailid = '" + sMailID + "' and sessionid = '" + sSessionID + "'");
    while (oRs.next()) {

        outputResult = oRs.getString(1);
        outputStream.write(outputResult.getBytes());
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + sFileName + ".txt\"");

    }
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();
```